# What is $x \times \sqrt x$

Tags: limits

Does $x \times \sqrt x  = x$?

I thought it was correct because sqrt is the opposite of multiplying by a number, so I figured by multiplying by a number it would balance out and be that number normally, but when I tried it with my Python calculator using 3 I got:

> math.sqrt(3) * 3
>   
>   5.196152422706632

Comment: You seem very confused... If it were true that $x\sqrt{x} = x$ for all $x$, that would imply $\sqrt{x} = 1$ for all $x$. The "opposite of multplying", if anything, is dividing, not taking square roots.

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is the number satisfying $\sqrt x \sqrt x = x$; it's not the opposite of multiplying by $x$.

Comment: Squareroot is the opposite of squaring. One can say for $x>0$ that $\sqrt{x}^2=x$ and that $\sqrt{x^2}=x.$

Comment: The inverse function of multiplication is division, while the inverse function of squaring a number is taking the square root of the result.

Comment: Also, why bother with Python? $\sqrt 4 = 2$, but $4 \cdot 2 \ne 4$.

Comment: @fkraiem Certainly, it would imply $\sqrt{x}=1$ or $x=0$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Python is fun? I dunno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. Since $\sqrt x$ is equal to $x^{1/2}$, your equation is the same as $x^{3/2} = x$, only $x = 0, 1$ work as solutions

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I understand now

Comment: Actually, $x=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: I overlooked that, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *solve* for the equation
$$
x\sqrt{x} = x
$$
then you have
$$
x (\sqrt{x}-1) =0 \Rightarrow x = 0, \text{ or } \sqrt{x}=1, \text{ i.e. } x = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative inverse (the "opposite" in your question) of a non-zero number $x$ is its reciprocal, $\frac{1}{x}$. Multiplying these two together gives instead $x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

so basically $\sqrt x$ is the same as $x^{1/2}$ and x can also be taken as $x^1$ that means when you multiply both of them you'll get $x^{1+1/2}$ which would be $x^{3/2}$

Comment: for any new people that may end up in this post like me